# Cursometer - Rendering a user's mouse speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousemove

Today, I was introduced to `cursometer`, a JQuery plugin that is designed to keep tabs on a user's cursor speed. I have studied this guide as a reference

http://www.loganfranken.com/blog/49/capturing-cursor-speed/

**HTML**

```
<p id="speed"></p>

<image src="http://hdwallpapersd.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/cool-background-for-designer-wallpaper.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('image').cursometer();

  var currSpeed = $('image').cursometer('getCurrentSpeed')

  $('#speed').html('Speed' + currSpeed);
});
```

When I `mousemove` the image, I'd like the cursor speed to be shown in the paragraph.

I created a fiddle for this

http://jsfiddle.net/4pj0vu9t/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code slightly ...

**HTML:** (note the class)

```
<p id="speed">Speed</p>
<image class='image' src="http://hdwallpapersd.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/cool-background-for-designer-wallpaper.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.image').cursometer({
        onUpdateSpeed: function (speed) {
            $('#speed').html('Speed: ' + speed);
        },
        updateSpeedRate: 20
    });
});
```

Basically, I've used the `onUpdateSpeed` to capture the speed change every 20ms. using the built in configuration options.  It didn't work without the class selector, so changed it to `class='image'`.

Your code only ran one time; this one repeats correctly.  Also, you need jQuery included.

**Working jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/4pj0vu9t/3/